# Dimension too large for TikZ modulo arithmetic

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{ifthen}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\def\sides{50}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\lmu{\sides -1}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\lmu} \draw (\i *360/\sides:3cm) node(\i){\i};
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\lmu} \draw let \n1={int(mod(\i+2,\sides))} in (\i) -- (\n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I try to do some modulo >40 pictures. I found particularly useful the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4281/15542). But now I found a `dimension too large`-limitation. Does anybody know how to overcome this?

Comment: Using `(\i/\side*360:3cm)` will circumvent it.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258701/third-grade-spiral-in-tikz-dimension-too-large?rq=1 is probably a duplicate.